# How do angles on a deflated balloon behave when I blow the balloon up?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

In Euclidean geometry on a flat plane, the interior angles of any triangle add up to $180$°, but this is not necessarily true in spherical geometry. This made me wonder if it was possible to predict the angles or the transformed shape of a triangle drawn on a deflated balloon when the balloon is inflated.

Intuitively, I feel that perpendicularity should at least be preserved in the process, but at the same time if a spherical triangle can exist on a balloon, does that mean I can draw a flat triangle on the deflated balloon in such a way that it becomes a spherical triangle when it is inflated?

I'm assuming the balloon will inflate to something approximately spherical, but I suppose the same question can be asked for other balloon shapes as well.

Comment: A sphere can have an equilateral triangle where all three angles are right-angles (consider an octant).  So if you deflate this to something flat, either the angles change or the edges stop being straight.   You might consider some map projections and their distortions as possible ways of deflating the balloon, some of which are more physically realistic than others

Comment: @Henry do you have some pointers for where I can learn more about projections in 3D? For example, for the balloon example, converting from a flat object with two circular faces that each map onto either vertical hemisphere of the spherical balloon when it's blown up (or vice versa)?

Comment: It's a reasonable question, but the answer depends on the details of how (and _if_ ...) the material of the balloon stretches under inflation.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I see, do you think this question is a better fit for Physics SE? Or are some variables *negligible* enough to justify doing maths on an idealised balloon?

Comment: I think "it depends" what type of answer you're seeking. A mylar balloon made by bonding two circular patches along the edges (essentially angle-preserving because nearly no stretching) behaves differently than a latex spheroid (angle-preserving if the stretching is uniform), which behaves differently from those long latex balloons used to make animal sculptures (probably non-uniform stretching?). Anyway, it's an appealing geometric question. (+1)